# Turn on or off Google Apps services programmatically

Tags: google-api, google-apps

Is there any way to turn on/off Google Apps services programmatically? There is such opportunity for administrators in  manual way: https://support.google.com/a/answer/182442?hl=en&ref_topic=4390547 But i have not found how to do it by code. I tried unsuccessfully to search among Admin SDK documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/ For example i need to switch on/off hangouts for some time peroid for selected users.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this programatically is to move the users between OUs with Hangouts enabled and disabled.